Resender usdt trc20/trx
Let's say there is a TRX wallet that constantly receives withdrawal requests 4 times per second. Is it possible to write code that will withdraw USDT faster than TRX is being transferred to another wallet?
If the code is not possible, is there a way to disable permissions on the wallet programmatically or by other methods to transfer tron?
I wrote a code that sends USDT withdrawal requests more frequently than TRX withdrawals, but TRX is still transferred faster.
It’s necessary to ensure that USDT is transferred faster than TRX after the TRX is received

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
